# Socket.io- unable to fix two errors

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io, chat

I'm writing a chat app in NodeJS with Socket.io. The browser console is showing me 2 Errors I have tried a lot but and I don't know how to fix it. Is there any way to fix these two errors? Get project code through my git repository: https://github.com/Hassan-1byte/ichat

This is my code:

**index.js**

```
const io = require('socket.io')(8000)
const users = {};
io.on('connection', socket =>{
socket.on('new-user-joined', name =>{ 
    users[socket.id] = name;
    socket.broadcast.emit('user-joined', name);
});

socket.on('send', message =>{
    socket.broadcast.emit('receive', {message: message, name: users[socket.id]})
});

socket.on('disconnect', message =>{
    socket.broadcast.emit('left', users[socket.id]);
    delete users[socket.id];
});
});
```

**client.js**

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:8000');
const form = document.getElementById('send-container');
const messageInput = document.getElementById('messageInp')
const messageContainer = document.querySelector(".container")

var audio = new Audio('ting.mp3');

const append = (message, position)=>{
const messageElement = document.createElement('div');
messageElement.innerText = message;
messageElement.classList.add('message');
messageElement.classList.add(position);
messageContainer.append(messageElement);
if(position =='left'){ 
    audio.play();
}
}

const name = prompt("Enter your name to join");
socket.emit('new-user-joined', name);

socket.on('user-joined', name =>{
append(`${name} joined the chat`, 'right')
})

// If server sends a message, receive it
socket.on('receive', data =>{
append(`${data.name}: ${data.message}`, 'left')
})

// If a user leaves the chat, append the info to the container
socket.on('left', name =>{
append(`${name} left the chat`, 'right')
})

// If the form gets submitted, send server the message
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
const message = messageInput.value;
append(`You: ${message}`, 'right');
socket.emit('send', message);
messageInput.value = ''
})
```

**Error Generated**

```
Error 1# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Error 2# Uncaught Reference Error: io is not defined at client.js:1
```

Comment: This sounds like the client-side did not successfully load the socket.io library.  If this is in a browser, please show the `<script>` tag that loads the socket.io library.  Also, for Error #1, please show the full error message including the URL of the resource that it is trying to load

Comment: <script defer src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>             <script defer src="js/client.js"></script>

Comment: Complete Error #1 with URL is this:                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Well, you socket.io server appears to be on port 8000, not 3000.

Comment: yeah Sorry !  Complete Error #1 with URL is this: GET localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: I don't honestly know if `http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js` is supported by a pure socket.io server (e.g. not an http server that you've added socket.io to).